# How do we migrate SSL certificate between sandboxes

Tags: deployment, migration-tool, migration, certificates

Can we migrate SSL certificates between sandboxes? I have a certificate uploaded in one sandbox and working fine and now intend to move all the pieces to another sandbox. I was hoping certificates are part of metadata which I can migrate using any migration tool.

What is the correct process to move the SSL certificate from the current sandbox to another sandbox?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally got the right way!, same certificates can be installed across sandboxes with the the below steps:
On the source sandbox

1. Security Controls -> Certificate and Key Management
2. Click on Export to Keystore
3. Provide a Keystore password
4. Click on export
5. A file Java Keystore format with extension .jks (e.g.
   00D180000001XWw.jks)

will get downloaded to local system

On target sandbox

1. Security Controls -> Certificate and Key Management
2. Click on Import from a Keystore
3. Choose downloaded jsk file and provide Keystore password and click on Save
4. All certificates inside the Keystore imported to target sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re using Ant for deployment you can put the following in both your “Retrieve from Source” `package.xml` as well as your “Deploy to Target” `package.xml` :

`<types>`
  
`<name>Certificate</name>`
  
`<members>*</members>`
`</types>`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to reconfigure the certificates across sandboxes. As far as I'm aware there is no way to deploy these. Might be a good idea to double check either way, because your URL will change when using a different sandbox and you might need a different certificate.